pattern matching using gsub
I am trying to search and replace multiple patterns of a string and replace it with different values. However the command is replacing only one pattern and ignoring the rest.
output=$(echo "$output4" | awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/\[|]/,""); gsub("+r","READ"); gsub("+r+w","READ and WRITE"); gsub("+r+w+g","READ, WRITE and GRANT"); print}')

When I execute the script, this is what I am getting.
    Group Analyst_Corp in security domain Native: READ. Group Finance_Dev in security domain Native: READ+w. Manufacturing_Corp in security domain Native: READ+w
Information_Tech in security domain Native: READ+w+g.

I am looking for the output like this.
        Group Analyst_Corp in security domain Native: READ. Group Finance_Dev in security domain Native: READ and WRITE. Manufacturing_Corp in security domain Native: READ and WRITE
    Information_Tech in security domain Native: READ, WRITE and GRANT.


What is the value of $output4?

You need to replace the longer patterns first. When you replace +r first, there won't be any +r+w in the line any more.

please update the question with the output from typeset -p output4

Please post $output4 value in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Guessing at OP's input (ie, contents of the output4 variable), and throwing in some [ and ] characters for good measure:
output4="Some line to ignore
    Group [Analyst_Corp] in security domain [Native]: +r. Group [Finance_Dev] in security domain [Native]: +r+w. [Manufacturing_Corp] in security domain [Native]: +r+w
[Information_Tech] in security domain [Native]: +r+w+g."

There are a few issues with the current code:

where patterns overlap in content you want to replace the longer strings (eg, +r+w+g) before replacing the shorter strings (eg, +r)
the + has a special meaning in regex patterns so to match on a literal + we need to escape it (\+ or [+])
when escaping with \ you'll run into fewer issues if you work with a static regex (pattern wrapped in a pair of / characters)
when escaping with [] you can use a dynamic (pattern wrapped in double quotes) or static regex
while the current code works for removing brackets ([, ]) we'll swap in a different regex that's a tad easier (?) to read/understand

A few different options for modifying OP's current code:
########
# static regex; using `\` to escape the '+'

awk 'NR>1 { gsub(/[][]/,"")                             # remove brackets '[' and ']'
            gsub(/\+r\+w\+g/,"READ, WRITE and GRANT")
            gsub(/\+r\+w/,"READ and WRITE")
            gsub(/\+r/,"READ")
            print
          }
' <<< "${output4}"

########
# dynamic regex; using '[]' to escape the '+'

awk 'NR>1 { gsub(/[][]/,"")
            gsub("[+]r[+]w[+]g","READ, WRITE and GRANT")
            gsub("[+]r[+]w","READ and WRITE")
            gsub("[+]r","READ")
            print
          }
' <<< "${output4}"

########
# static regex; using '[]' to escape the '+'

awk 'NR>1 { gsub(/[][]/,"")
            gsub(/[+]r[+]w[+]g/,"READ, WRITE and GRANT")
            gsub(/[+]r[+]w/,"READ and WRITE")
            gsub(/[+]r/,"READ")
            print
          }
' <<< "${output4}"

All of these generate:
    Group Analyst_Corp in security domain Native: READ. Group Finance_Dev in security domain Native: READ and WRITE. Manufacturing_Corp in security domain Native: READ and WRITE
Information_Tech in security domain Native: READ, WRITE and GRANT.

Collapsing down to one-liners and storing results in variable output:
output=$(awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/[][]/,""); gsub(/\+r\+w\+g/,"READ, WRITE and GRANT"); gsub(/\+r\+w/,"READ and WRITE"); gsub(/\+r/,"READ"); print} ' <<< "${output4}")

output=$(awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/[][]/,""); gsub("[+]r[+]w[+]g","READ, WRITE and GRANT"); gsub("[+]r[+]w","READ and WRITE"); gsub("[+]r","READ"); print} ' <<< "${output4}")

output=$(awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/[][]/,""); gsub(/[+]r[+]w[+]g/,"READ, WRITE and GRANT"); gsub(/[+]r[+]w/,"READ and WRITE"); gsub(/[+]r/,"READ"); print} ' <<< "${output4}")

All of these generate:
$ typeset -p output
declare -- output="        Group Analyst_Corp in security domain Native: READ. Group Finance_Dev in security domain Native: READ and WRITE. Manufacturing_Corp in security domain Native: READ and WRITE
    Information_Tech in security domain Native: READ, WRITE and GRANT."


Replace the overlapping patterns in descending order of length. Otherwise, it can't find +r+w after it replaces +r.
awk 'NR>1 {
    gsub(/\[|]/,""); 
    gsub(/\+r\+w\+g\/,"READ, WRITE and GRANT"); 
    gsub(/\+r\+w/,"READ and WRITE"); 
    gsub(/\+r/,"READ"); 
    print}'

You also need to escape +, since it has special meaning in regular expressions.

If you are okay with slightly different (but same meaning) output, you might replace
gsub("+r","READ"); gsub("+r+w","READ and WRITE"); gsub("+r+w+g","READ, WRITE and GRANT")

using
gsub("[+]r","READ"); gsub("[+]w"," and WRITE"); gsub("[+]g"," and GRANT")

let file.txt content be
this +r is limited to read, whilst +r+w can also write, whilst +r+w+g has also right to grant

then
awk '{gsub("[+]r","READ"); gsub("[+]w"," and WRITE"); gsub("[+]g"," and GRANT"); print}' file.txt

gives output
this READ is limited to read, whilst READ and WRITE can also write, whilst READ and WRITE and GRANT has also right to grant

note there is READ and WRITE and GRANT rather than READ, WRITE and GRANT and will be also applied to standalone +w and +g.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
